# How to take average of top 10 scores if player played 10 games

Tags: mysql

I have a table GAMES with -

| g_id | player1 | player2 | player1_score | player2_score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 320 | 321 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 230 | 300 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 341 | 320 |
| 4 | 2 | 4 | 281 | 311 |
| 5 | 4 | 1 | 256 | 255 |
| 6 | 3 | 1 | 321 | 333 |

table continues like this..

I want to create a leader board which contains average of top 10 scores of every player(if he has played 10 games)

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have edited the question.hope my question is clear now.Thank you

Comment: You still haven't shared your attempts to resolve the problem, nor the expected output